# How to get context of the command in chrome console using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, ruby, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried the below but it didnt helped me.,

```
puts @driver.execute_script("window.dataLayer[0]")
puts @driver.execute_script("console.log(window.dataLayer[0])")
```

When I enter dataLayer manually in the chrome console, I get the objects displayed as shown in the below image. What I need is to extract or print those data using Selenium.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! I missed to return the value. Here is it,

```
@x = @driver.execute_script("return window.dataLayer[0]")
puts @x
```

or

```
puts @driver.execute_script("function value() { return window.dataLayer[0]; } return value();")
```